# Problem with compile ReactJs: Error in App.js Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I followed the following command line.

```
npx create-react-app github-first-app

npm install --save react-tabs

npm i styled-components

npm install git-state --save
```

with the following code files

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "./components/layout";
import NoSearch from "./components/no-search";
import Profile from "./components/profile";
import Repositories from "./components/repositories";
import useGithub from "./hooks/github-hooks";

const App = () => {
  const { githubState } = useGithub();
  return (
    <Layout>
      {githubState.hasUser ? (
        <>
          {githubState.loading ? (
            <p>Loading</p>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Profile />
              <Repositories />
            </>
          )}
        </>
      ) : (
        <NoSearch />
      )}
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>Github Interface</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

but

```
npm start
```

it fails completely with a message that doesn't help a novice at all.

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/App.js
> Syntax error:
> C:/Workspace/bootcamps/022_CriandoUmFrontEndTotalmenteComponentizadoNaPraticaComReactJS/github-
> first-app/src/App.js: Unexpected token (13:9)

Could you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What happens if you replace `<>` with `<React.Fragment>`? (btw I don't think `--save` is needed anymore)

Comment: I'm not sure why but I find the `<>` fragment shorthand isn't always recognised. Try `<React.Fragment>` instead, and the same of course for the closing tag. (Line 13 is the `<>` tag, is how I'm suspecting this.)

Answer (score 1):

As per React documentation, support for JSX fragments is available in [Babel v7.0.0-beta.31](https://github.com/babel/babel/releases/tag/v7.0.0-beta.31) and above!

[Docs Link](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#support-for-fragment-syntax)

**Use `<React.Fragment>` instead**